# Plot a table of binomial distributions in R

Tags: r, dice

For a game design issue, I need to better inspect binomial distributions. Using **R**, I need to build a two dimensional table that - given a fixed parameters 'pool' (the number of dice rolled), 'sides' (the number of sides of the die) has:

- In rows --> minimum for a success (ranging from 0 to sides, it's a discrete distribution)
- In columns --> number of successes (ranging from 0 to pool)

I know how to calculate it as a single task, but I'm not sure on how to iterate to fill the entire table

**EDIT:**  I forgot to say that I want to calculate the probability p of gaining at least the number of successes.

Comment: It looks like this is a programming issue. If so, this would be better served on Stack Overflow, and a moderator can migrate this question for you (flag this post, but don't repost on SO).

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: one way is to simply keep going until you have rolled all values at least once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i think this could be a simple solution. It has ratio of successes on rows and success thresholds on dice roll (p) on columns.

```
poolDistribution <- function(n, sides=10, digits=2, roll.Under=FALSE){
  m <- 1:sides
  names(m) <- paste(m,ifelse(roll.Under,"-", "+"),sep="")
  s <- 1:n
  names(s) <- paste(s,n,sep="/")
  sapply(m, function(m.value) round((if(roll.Under) (1 - pbinom(s - 1, n, (m.value)/sides))*100 else (1 - pbinom(s - 1, n, (sides - m.value + 1)/sides))*100), digits=digits))
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets you half of the way.
If you are new to `R`, you might miss out on the fact that a very powerful feature is that you can use a vector of values as an index to another vector.  This makes part of the problem trivially easy:

```
pool <- 3
sides <- 20  # <cough>D&D<cough>


# you need to strore the values somewhere, use a vector
NumberOfRollsPerSide <- rep(0, sides)
names(NumberOfRollsPerSide) <- 1:sides # this will be useful in table

## Repeast so long as there are still zeros
##     ie, so long as there is a side that has not come up yet
while (any(NumberOfRollsPerSide == 0)) {
  # roll once
  oneRoll <- sample(1:sides, pool, TRUE)  

  # add (+1) to each sides' total rolls
  #  note that you can use the roll outcome to index the vector. R is great. 
  NumberOfRollsPerSide[oneRoll] <- NumberOfRollsPerSide[oneRoll] + 1
}

# These are your results: 
  NumberOfRollsPerSide
```

All you have left to do now is count, for each side, in which roll number it first came up.

Comment: ehehe tnx, it's not my homework. Unfortunately, I'm too old to be at college ;) We just decided to spice up our RPG *cough*non D20-based*cough* design activities with more statistical rigor. I'm not totally new to R, but I usually use it for analysis rather than real programming. But lemme try your code now! :) tnx for your answer!

Comment: while this is not what i need to calculate (I edited the question accordingly), your snippet of code is still purely useful for something else i need to analyze! Tnx allot for your contribute!

Comment: Surely if it was D&D, it would be 3d6 *AHEM*